# Как от андройд устройства получить его “Product ID”? adb fastboot

Tags: android, adb

Как от андройд устройства с операционнкой 2.3.4 получить его "Product ID"?
Пробую через консольное приложение для PC "ADB" используя команды FastBoot:

делаю запрос командой
`--- fastboot devices`
отдаёт
`--- K   fastboot` 
делаю запрос командой
`--- fastboot oem get-bootinfo`
отдаёт 
`--- ...`
и виснет
что делать, как быть? подскажите если кто понял!

Предполагаю что это указывает на то, что функционал намеренно был заблокирован производителем. Можно ли это как то обойти и всё таки получить "Product ID" ?